# Display text from text area over several lines

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this bit of code:

```
<?php $fields = get_acf(); echo $fields->event_address; ?>
```

This outputs an address from a text area box in Wordpress. In that box I've written the address like this:

> Address line 1,
>
> Address line 2,
>
> Address line 3

With the variable at the top it outputs all the info on one line (it doesn't recognise the address is over 3 lines), is it possible to do something clever to get it to display over 3 lines.

I know I could quite easily add more fields to Wordpress to show the 3 lines but I'd like something a bit more neat than that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try solving this with pure css:

```
p {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

The paragraph behaves like the `<pre>` tag afterwards, breaking visually at line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Use it like so `echo nl2br($fields->event_address);`

In your text box if you just remove the lines between the addresses so they look like so

```
Address
Address
Address
```

That should do it...

Comment: It's adding 2 br's, is there any way I could change it to add 1 br. But yes along the right lines!!

Comment: @Rob see answer modification.

Comment: Yep that's how it's set out, seems a bit odd that it's inserting two br's.

Comment: It's just a text area box with with pure text in it, I can't work out where the extra br's are coming from but the text area is set out exactly as you've put it. Very strange!